# Como deixar tamanho minimo de coluna de um table no css

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Preciso deixar um tamanho minimo na coluna descrição para que descrições muito grandes quebrem poucas linhas, sei apenas colocar o tamanho fixo, porem não o minimo que ela pode chegar

ps: ela é responsiva!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo é fortemente aconselhável **não** utilizar código em imagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe a propriedade `min-height` do css.

O que da pra fazer é criar uma classe com essa propriedade:

`.foo {
    min-height: 300px;
}`

Como sugerido nesse post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432092/can-i-use-a-min-height-for-table-tr-or-td